# How to transfer data from Lightning page to VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-apps

I have two pages. Page 1(Lightning) & Page 2(VF page). I'm entering Firstname and Lastname in page 1 and these values should get captured and send to the page 2,also these values should be populated in the page 2 fields. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i used for sending data from lightning to vf page , i hope this will help you

Here is my lightning code

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="vfHost" type="String"
            default="yourdomain-dev-ed--c.na35.visual.force.com"/>

    <!-- Input field for message "data" -->
    <lightning:input type="text" label="Message:" value="{!v.message}"/>
    <lightning:button label="Send to VF" onclick="{!c.sendToVF}"/>

    <!-- The Visualforce page to send data to -->
    <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/myvfpage'}"/>

</aura:component>
```

- vfHost is the host Visualforce pages are loaded from in your environment. In a real-life application, you should obtain this value dynamically instead of hardcoding it. *

Lightning controller -

```
({
    sendToVF : function(component, event, helper) {
        var message = component.get("v.message");
        var vfOrigin = "https://" + component.get("v.vfHost");
        var vfWindow = component.find("vfFrame").getElement().contentWindow;
        vfWindow.postMessage(message, vfOrigin);
    }
})
```

Here is the vf page -

```
<apex:page>

<script>
    var lexOrigin = "https://yourdomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com";
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
            // Not the expected origin: reject message!
            return;
        }
        // Handle message
        console.log(event.data);
    }, false);
</script>

</apex:page>
```

If you need any more help, let me know